# Passing Variables into a customer terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build a module in terraform that can be passed a variable map from a workspace file and lookup the variables to build an AWS CodePipeline.  For those not aware, CodePipeline has a series of stages, and inside those stages are actions.  My module needs to handle building a pipeline wiht any supported number of stages and actions within those stages.

Below is a part of the module I've wirtten concerned with the creation of the pipeline itself:

```
dynamic "stage" {
    for_each = [for s in var.stages : {
      name   = s.name
      action = s.action
    } if(lookup(s, "enabled", true))]

    content {
      name = stage.value.name
      dynamic "action" {
        for_each = stage.value.action
        content {
          name             = lookup(action.value, "name", null)
          owner            = lookup(action.value, "owner", null)
          version          = lookup(action.value, "version", null)
          category         = lookup(action.value, "category", null)
          provider         = lookup(action.value, "provider", null)
          input_artifacts  = lookup(action.value, "input_artifacts", null)
          output_artifacts = lookup(action.value, "output_artifacts", null)
          configuration    = {
            BranchName           = lookup(action.value, "BranchName", null)
            PollForSourceChanges = lookup(action.value, "PollForSourceChanges", null)
            RepositoryName       = lookup(action.value, "RepositoryName", null)
            ProjectName          = lookup(action.value, "ProjectName", null)
          }
          role_arn         = lookup(action.value, "role_arn", null)
          run_order        = lookup(action.value, "run_order", null)
          region           = lookup(action.value, "region", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  tags = merge(
    { "Name" = "${var.prefix}-${var.name}" },
    var.tags,
  )
}
```

And here is an excerpt from the workspace yaml, where I pass the variables for two stages, each with an associated action:

```
test_pipeline_prefix: "test"
test_pipeline_name: "test-pipeline"
test_pipeline_description: "this is a POC pipeline"
test_pipeline_s3: "<<REDACTED ARN>>"
test_pipeline_codestar_arn: "<<REDACTED ARN>>"
test_pipeline_tags: [""]

test_pipeline_stages: [{
  name: "Source",
  action: [{
    name                   = "Source",
    category               = "Source",
    owner                  = "AWS"
    version                = "1",
    provider               = "CodeStarSourceConnection",
    output_artifacts       = "source_output",
    BranchName             = "main",
    PollForSourceChanges   = "false",
    RepositoryName         = "<<REDACTED REPO>>",
    region                 = "eu-west-2",
    run_order              = 1
  }]
},
{
  name: "Plan",
  action: [{
    name                   = "Plan",
    category               = "Build",
    owner                  = "AWS"
    version                = "1",
    provider               = "CodeBuild",
    input_artifacts        = "source_output",
    output_artifacts       = "build_output",
    ProjectName            = "pipeline-plan",
    run_order              = 2
  }]
}]
```

Finally I call it with:

```
module "codepipeline" {
  source         = "./modules/codepipeline"
  s3             = local.vars.test_pipeline_s3
  description    = local.vars.test_pipeline_description
  prefix         = local.vars.test_pipeline_prefix
  name           = local.vars.test_pipeline_name
  stages         = local.vars.test_pipeline_stages
  codestar_arn   = local.vars.test_pipeline_codestar_arn

  tags = {
    Environment = local.vars.env
    Terraform = "true"
  }
}
```

What I am hoping for it to do, is loop through the stages and actions in the "test_pipeline_stages" variable supplied, and loop through to create a stage for the Source, with an action configured to connect to the preexsiting CodeStar connection, and another stage called "Plan" that runs the CodeBuild job as it's action.

The result I'm actually getting is:

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.0.action.0.owner" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.0.action.0.provider" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.0.action.0.category" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.0.action.0.version" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.1.action.0.version" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.1.action.0.category" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.1.action.0.owner" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
│ 
│ The argument "stage.1.action.0.provider" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    2:   name     = "${var.prefix}-${var.name}"
│ 
│ The argument "stage.0.action.0.name" is required, but no definition was
│ found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.this,
│   on modules/codepipeline/main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "this":
│    2:   name     = "${var.prefix}-${var.name}"
│ 
│ The argument "stage.1.action.0.name" is required, but no definition was
│ found.
```

This suggest to me that its not indexing the variables prporly but I can't really figure the best way to proceed.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention: note that the error log above is a complete list of the errors I get.  Which means some of the lookups are working, but not others?  For instance it can find BranchName or RepositoryName, but not name or owner...

Comment: Try replacing `action.value` with the corresponding argument, i.e., for name `action.name` etc.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE I've given that a go but I'm getting an error saying: "The given key does not identify an element in this collection value."

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about `lookup`. And if you set the second `for_each` to use `for_each = stage.action`?

Comment: Having a `lookup` call that falls back to `null` for a required argument like `owner` seems a bit suspect, because it would never be valid for that argument to be omitted anyway. If you remove the `lookup` calls from the arguments that are required and just refer directly to e.g. `action.value.owner`, does Terraform give you a more informative error message? I worry that your attempts to suppress the lookup errors might be hiding what the real problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to responders so far - the actual fix I'll detail below, but all responses up to this point have helped me get there.  I also agree that supplying null values as a fallback is not sensible; I'll look to review that.

The actual issue was simply that my workspace yaml as posted above is... not valid yaml.  Once I replaced it with the below, the module began to read out the values correctly.

```
test_pipeline_stages: [{
  name: "Source",
  action: [{
    ActionName: "Source",
    ActionCategory: "Source",
    ActionOwner: "AWS",
    ActionVersion: "1",
    ActionProvider: "CodeStarSourceConnection",
    output_artifacts: ["source_output"],
    BranchName: "main",
    PollForSourceChanges: "false",
    RepositoryName: "REDACTED",
    ConnectionArn: "REDACTED",
    region: "eu-west-2",
    run_order: 1
  }]
},
{
  name: "Plan",
  action: [{
    ActionName: "Plan",
    ActionCategory: "Build",
    ActionOwner: "AWS",
    ActionVersion: "1",
    ActionProvider: "CodeBuild",
    input_artifacts: ["source_output"],
    output_artifacts: ["build_output"],
    ProjectName: "pipeline-plan",
    test_pipeline_ans_tags: "",
    run_order: 2
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Would you be willing to share your locals.tf to see how you flattened your Yaml file?   The work is impressive.

Comment: I'm away at the moment but will add it this week!

Answer (score 0):

comma is missing after owner= "AWS", put comma in workspace file.

Comment: Well spotted; this didn't resolve the issue but it certainly didn't help!!